# Waiting for the message, but the bot does not respond

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx, channel_name):
    channel_id = int(''.join(i for i in channel_name if i.isdigit()))
    existing_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await ctx.send("Please confirm nuke: type yes or no")

    def check(m):
        return m.content == 'yes'

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if existing_channel is not None:
        await existing_channel.clone(reason="Has been nuked")
        await existing_channel.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'No channel named **{channel_name}** was found')

    def check(s):
        return s.content == 'no'
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await ctx.send("Nuke has been canceled")
```

The problem I'm having:
The bot should supposedly cancel the command once you say no, but it does not cancel the command. If you were to say yes right after saying no, the bot proceeds to clone and delete the channel anyway. There are no error messages either. If you need any other information, please let me know.

[image: The bot does not respond to no, but if you say yes right after it deletes anyway]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the line `msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)` pause execution until the condition `m.content == 'yes'` is met? This should work better:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx, channel_name):
    channel_id = int(''.join(i for i in channel_name if i.isdigit()))
    existing_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await ctx.send("Please confirm nuke: type yes or no")

    def check(m):
        return m.content == 'yes' or m.content == 'no'

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    if msg.content == 'yes':
        if existing_channel is not None:
            await existing_channel.clone(reason="Has been nuked")
            await existing_channel.delete()
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'No channel named **{channel_name}** was found')
    elif msg.content == 'no':
        await ctx.send("Nuke has been canceled")
```